# Nested #equals in SendGrid Handlebars

Tags: nested, handlebars.js, sendgrid

I'm trying to make this work:

```
<table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center" align="center">
            {{#equals this.rollupRegion 'South'}}
            <img src="http://cdn.mcauto-images-production.sendgrid.net/.../0945bd18-ff2e-4ce1-8f3f-72cf4877d66d/1063x524.jpg" width="70%">                 
            {{else}}
                {{#equals this.rollupRegion 'Mid Atlantic'}}
                <img src="http://cdn.mcauto-images-production.sendgrid.net/.../d23b3813-2754-403d-88de-38c1c762c966/1063x540.jpg" width="70%">  
                {{else}}
                <img src="http://cdn.mcauto-images-production.sendgrid.net/.../7136888c-9800-495e-a325-a165cf7a30d5/1064x540.jpg" width="70%">
                {{/equals}}
            {{/equals}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I simply can't see anybody having the same question/issue. Their preview doesn't show an error message but doesn't render the images correctly. Basically, only the first condition is checked. Any other rollupRegion I provide gets to the bottom else.

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't working. The code looks correct to me. However, assuming the `#equals` helper abides by standard Handlebars rules, you can do this without a nested `#equal` - and just maybe that will work. `{{#equals this.rollupRegion 'South'}}{{!-- South image --}}{{else equals this.rollupRegion 'Mid Atlantic'}}{{!-- Mid Atlantic image --}}{{else}}{{!-- Other image --}}{{/equals}}`

Comment: I have the same issue with `#and` and `#or` helpers. It's annoying as I'm not sure what workaround is available for this issue.

Comment: My only guess is with a somewhat similar situation where we had a `{{#if }} {{else}}` within another. I suppose the code doesn't understand to which 'if' each 'else' belong to. Using two conditions instead of if/else fixed our issue.